# Executing BAT command when using folder names with spaces (Server 2019)

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-line-arguments, windows-server-2019, space

Hell all, I have a bat script that attempts to run 3 different programs, but one of them does not work properly.  Below is the current script, where the first 2 item run normally but the last item does not.  I'm sure it's because of the space in the folder names, but I have tried every combination of adding additional quotes to account for the space, and none of them has worked.  Either the program does not run at all, or when it does run, Windows will add an extra space in the details, and therefor it doesn't actually work.

Current script text: (which runs via Windows Task Scheduler)

```
P:

CD \PPART
START "" P:\ppart\Connect.exe "P:\ppart\Interface\Medisoft\Rcv\DemSch\DemSch_Rcv.ini"
START "" P:\ppart\Connect.exe "P:\ppart\Interface\Medisoft\Snd\BillCode\BillCode_Snd.ini"
START "" "P:\ppart\Interface\Connect\Tribal Diagnostic\Connect.exe" "P:\ppart\Interface\Connect\Tribal Diagnostic\Rcv\Lab\Lab_Rcv.ini""
END
```

This is what runs in task manager:  Note that the line highlighted is what I want to run (and this works when i manually run a desktop shortcut to execute the program.)  But the line below is what runs from the batch command, and Windows has added an extra space between the program and argument.

[image]

I was trying to automate this via a batch command, but if there is an easier way to just run a shortcut that opens the App, that would work as well.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The quotes on the the failing line do not pair up. Replace `""` at the end with `"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I removed the last " in the command, but after testing, it's the same result.  I still see the extra space between the path and target commands, in the running process details.

Comment: Right. Try using `""` at the start **and** the end

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d p:\ppart

start "" Connect.exe .\Interface\Medisoft\Rcv\DemSch\DemSch_Rcv.ini
start "" Connect.exe .\Interface\Medisoft\Snd\BillCode\BillCode_Snd.ini
start "" .\Interface\Connect\"Tribal Diagnostic\Connect.exe" .\Interface\Connect\"Tribal Diagnostic"\Rcv\Lab\Lab_Rcv.ini
```

---

```bat
:: Try replace ::
P:
CD \PPART

:: per ::
cd /d P:\PART
```

Invoke the executable using current or relative path where necessary, and use that in arguments too, and as for quotes, use where necessary.